# Implicit function types in Scala

Tags: scala, function, types, functional-programming, implicit

Recently, I have become interested in implicit functions. In the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html), we can see several examples of using this property, but I think I do not quite understand how it works.

For example, we can read that `implicit T0 => R` is actually

```
trait ImplicitFunction1[-T0, R] extends Function1[T0, R] {
  override def apply(implicit x: T0): R
}
```

After writing the function below

```
val func = {implicit x: Int => 2*x}
```

I tried to use it in this way

```
implicit val x: Int = 3
println(func)
```

But it doesn't seem to work (only the `<function1>` type is returned, it looks like `apply` hasn't been used at all). If I had a method for it, it would work fine

```
def func(implicit x: Int) = 2*x
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit function types work in Dotty

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/implicit-function-types.html

https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2016/12/05/implicit-function-types.html

In Scala 2 `func` has type `Int => Int` instead of absent `implicit Int => Int` (aka `given Int => Int`).

`implicit x: Int => ???` is just a shorthand for `x: Int => { implicit val _x: Int = x; ???}`.

Out of all new `implicit` (aka `given`) features in Dotty only by-name implicits were backported to Scala 2.13.0.

Comment: Wow, by-name implicits were backported to scala 2.13? So there is no need for Lazy type in shapeless? Saw the status is still 'PENDING' https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/byname-implicits.html

Comment: @tribbloid By-name implicits were added in 2.13.0 https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0 By-name implicits and `shapeless.Lazy` are not equivalent. I guess I met cases when one helped while the other didn't. Also you can write `def foo(implicit tc: Lazy[TC[A]]): tc.value.Out = ???` but you can't write `def foo(implicit tc: => TC[A]): tc.Out = ???`. So `Lazy` is still necessary.